# Get Middle Name Initials from Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I am getting an error in setting middleName equal to entry.GetContact.Initials.

It is saying Object variable or with block not set

Is there another way to access the initials of a user's middle name?

```
Dim firstName, lastName, middleName, email As String

For Each entry In exUser.GetDirectReports() 'each entry is an exchangeUser
    firstName = entry.GetExchangeUser.firstName
    lastName = entry.GetExchangeUser.lastName
    middleName = entry.GetContact.Initials
    email = entry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
Next entry
```

Comment: Help others help you http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve some may not want to key all the parts needed to see the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetContact` returns a `ContactItem` object that exists on top of an `IPM.Contact` message in one of your Contacts folders. It obviously does not exist for a GAL user.

Why not simply concatenate the first letters of the first and last names?

Comment: Sorry, I should have worded this better but what I want initials to be is the initials of a persons middle name.  In outlook there is a field called initials where the middle name initials are stored

Comment: Retrieve the PR_MIDDLE_NAME MAPI property using AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty. The DALS property name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A44001F`